# Is there any option to build a single java file in the project

Tags: java, netbeans

I am doing my project in struts2 and hibernate. My project is little bit long and my problem is when done a small change in java file i have to clean and built the entire project and it is taking very long time to run the project. Is there any option to create the java class for the files that i have changed only, i am using netbeans editor as editor.

Comment: why should you clean and build ? Netbeans automatically compiles the modified class.

Comment: do you compile using the command line (javac) or a build tool?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called ***compile on save*** in the project properties.The modified classes are automatically compiled by netbeans.

[image]

Comment: I have already check this option but the change is not shown when i edit the java file

Answer (score 1):

By default Netbeans is going to use its *compile on save* mode, as mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738165/1097346). Everytime you modify and save a file, it automatically tries to compile it (as well as required dependencies if any).

While this mode is active, you have no per-file control on compilation and very little control over project compilation either. Your only option is Run -> Clean & Build which deletes any auto-compiled class, compiles everything again and builds a JAR out of your project.

As such, to control single-file compilation, you first need to uncheck the *Compile on Save* option in the Build/Compiling section of your project properties (right click on project in Projects tab, click on Properties). Once done, you get a new option in the Run menu: *Compile File* (associated to F9 by default). Of course, it also means you will now need to manually launch builds through the Run menu whenever it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "Debug / Apply Code changes" as long as your class-structure is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the file in project explorer, and choose **Run File**

mac OSX: **<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> + <kbd>(fn)</kbd>**