# How to compile single Java file in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have following code in project called Fork.

```
package fork;

public class Fork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       if (args.length == 1 | args[1].equals("test")) {
           System.out.println("test case");
       } else {
           System.out.println("production " + args[0]);
       }      

    }

}
```

Project Structure in Netbeans is as follows:

[image: Project Structure in NetBeans]

I am trying to make changes in the Fork.java. It would not build successfully because args[ 1 ] gives an error on runtime, which is alright. So, What I do is compile the Fork.java using "javac Fork.java" command in Terminal outside Netbeans. Then the changes reflect in the output.

For instance, I would run the following command from Terminal in my Mac or from the Terminal within Netbeans (both respond same way):
"java Fork live test"

Then I would make some changes in Fork.java and Save it. I have "Compile on save" enabled in my project properties.

I would run again the above command, but the changes would not reflect in the output. To see the changes, I would have to go to the Folder where Fork.java is saved, and then compile it using "javac Fork.java" in Terminal. Then I would run the "java Fork live test" from Terminal and see the changes.

***I am interested to see whether Netbeans has any equivalent way to compile a single file.***

Comment: Defect one. You have two arguments, so `args.length == 2`. Defect two. You used the non-short-circuiting or when you wanted the short-circuiting `&&`.

Comment: The condition in the IF statement does not matter. I am concerned about how I can recompile the java file after making even a trivial change. Let us assume, I correct the *defects* as you mentioned, How can I recompile only the said java file ? I must say that the code I gave above works like a charm in a way it should. My query is something else, if i could get my point across.

Comment: Your point is fine. I don't typically use Netbeans. These are called comments. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any option to build a single java file in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9738015/2985643)

Comment: I just verified that [this SO answer is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121998/2985643): _you first need to uncheck the Compile on Save option in the Build/Compiling section of your project properties (right click on project in Projects tab, click on Properties). Once done, you get a new option in the Run menu: Compile File (associated to F9 by default)_

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to run Fork with arguments (live test) using the NetBeans IDE. You don't want to go through the command line.

1. Right Click on Cup and Saucer icon -> Properties
2. Go to Run, add **live test** in the Arguments box
3. Run Project F6.

You code builds successfully using Clean and Build Project Shift+F11

Comment: How does this answer address the question in the OP: how to compile **a single file** in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

F9 compiles the current file in your editor window

Comment: It does, but F9 is disabled by default.